# Parsing xml file using xpath and xquery

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xquery

I have a xml file

```
<category>
    <type name="SWEATERS">
        <product id =1>
            <itemNumber>1</itemNumber>
            <name>ProductA2</name>
            <price>345</price>
        </product>
        <product id=2>
            <itemNumber>4</itemNumber>
            <name>Product Test </name>
            <price>456</price>
        </product>
    </type>
</category>
```

I used the xquery

```
$xml->xpath('//category/type/product[@id=1]');
```

When i used this xquery iam getting only the name and price.How i can get the type name 'SWEATERS' along with name and price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i used this xquery iam getting
>   only the name and price.How i can get
>   the type name 'SWEATERS' along with
>   name and price

The XPath 1.0 expression should be:

```
//category/type/product[itemNumber=1]/*[self::name or self::price]|
//category/type[product[itemNumber=1]]
```

Or more staticly:

```
//category/type/product[itemNumber=1]/*[self::name or self::price]|
//category/type[@name='SWEATERS']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the type element, you have to change your expression to:

`//category/type[product/itemNumber=1]`

Or for just the name:

`//category/type[product/itemNumber=1]/@name`

Comment: It is working fine.But it giving all the values with item number 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do it with a single query with Xpath but you can do it with `DOMNode->parentNode`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
$xml->xpath('//category/type[product/itemNumber=1]/(@name | product[itemNumber=1]/(name | price))');
```

this selects one attribute and two elements. The `|` is a union operator